# Question about the proof of Whitney's Embedding Theorem in the book by Lee

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about the proof of Whitney's Embedding Theorem in the book 'Introduction to smooth manifolds' by Lee (Theorem 6.15).

In the proof for the non-compact case I don't understand, why there is (only) one term which is in *both* sums nonzero in an neighbourhood of each point. I think this is true by the choice of $F$, $D_i$ and $E_i$, but I am failing to see this properly.
The point in the proof is marked in the figure below
[image]

Comment: When is $\rho_i(p)$ non-zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A =  \{q \in M \ \vert \ \ \rho_i(q) \neq 0 \}$. By construction,

$$\operatorname{supp}(\rho_i) =\overline{A} \subset \operatorname{Int}(E_i) \subset E_i$$

where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$. Also by construction:

$$E_{2k} \cap E_{2n} = \emptyset, \text{ for all } k \neq n$$

So suppose $i = 2k \in \mathbb{N}$ is even and $x \in M$ satisfies  $\rho_i(x) \neq 0$. Then by the definition of $\operatorname{supp}(\rho_i)$, $x \in E_i$. But since even $E_j$'s are disjoint, $x \notin E_{2n}$ for all $n \neq k$. This implies that $\rho_{2k}(x) = 0$ for all $k \neq n$ (otherwise we would have $x \in E_{2k}$ and $x$ would be a witness to the fact $E_{2k} \cap E_{2n} \neq \emptyset$, which is absurd by construction). In other words, only one term in the first sum is non-zero in a neighbourhood of each point. Mutatis mutandis, the same is true for the second sum which sums over all odd $i$'s instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I thought that the author means, that at  a same x the first two components both need a nonzero element in the sum. But I think what you have shown is everything, we need to know in the proof.